# Cloud formation: when is it safe to delete templates / stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

How do I know when it's safe to delete a cloud formation template?

Is there a way to list the resources that will be deleted when a template is deleted?

It is just the resources listed in the *Resources* tab of a stack view?

[illustration of what I'm referring to by "Resources stack view tab"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr49e.png)

I'd just like some assurance I'm not going to be erasing resources external to the stack, if that makes sense.

Thanks.

**Background**:

My company does not use Cloud Formation. Anything created by it is not in use. We want to get rid of it. It's part of a larger task for cleaning up AWS resources.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, check the resources tab of the stack, that shows the resources created. I suggest you run a backup / snapshot of any resources that can be backed up such as EC2 / RDS / S3 before you delete the stack. Also save a copy of the template.